# Create file java on wildfly

Tags: java, file, wildfly

I'm trying to create a file on the following code:

```
@GET
@Path("/download/{id}")
public void download(@PathParam("id") String id) throws IOException, DbxApiException, DbxException {

    Logger log = Logger.getLogger("thread");
    log.setLevel(Level.INFO);

    DbxRequestConfig config = new DbxRequestConfig("Lechucico");
    DbxClientV2 client = new DbxClientV2(config,"<acces_key>");

    File inputFile = new File("/dbfiles/test.txt");
    inputFile.createNewFile();

    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("/dbfiles/test.txt");
    client.files().download(id).download(outputStream);
    outputStream.close();
}
```

This is deployed on a wildfly server as a `.WAR`

The folder dbfiles has 777 permisions. I don't know why I can't create that file because there it have permisions.

I've got the following error:

> 11:48:56,036 ERROR [io.undertow.request] (default task-8) UT005023:
>   Exception handling request to /DropboxRest/app/dropbox/download/1:
>   org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException:
>   java.io.FileNotFoundException: test.txt (Permission denied)

Comment: The older files having those permissions doesn't matter when writing a new file. Check the permissions on the folder.

Comment: /dbfiles has the following permisions: `drwxrwxrwx.  2 root root`

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, that f from "folder dbfiles" slipped my eyes :)

Comment: new File() doesn't create the file itself; show us how do you create the file and where the exception is being thrown from.

Comment: I've updated with all the code.

Comment: I've redeployed the app on wildfly, and now it creates the files correctly. Don't know what was happening before.

Comment: [What does a dot after the file permission bits mean?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/102624/what-does-a-dot-after-the-file-permission-bits-mean/)

Comment: Did you change anything on wildfly? Also, some times the IDE tries to deploy BEFORE wildfly has finished starting and this generates all sorts of errors... Thats why I always double run a project when it has an error. Did that error happened on that session first run of wildfly?